# Pass Variables to SSIS package C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I am wanting to pass a couple of Variables into my SSIS package when calling it but I can't seem to get the correct syntax for it to work.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.Application();

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackage100 pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, false, null);
```

So the above bits work but when I go to add a variable it does not work:

```
pkg.Variables["mode"].Value = "test";
```

The error I am getting:

```
'IDTSPackage100' does not contain a definition for 'Variables' and no extension method 'Variables' accepting a first argument of type 'IDTSPackage100' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'
```

Comment: if I remember correctly you need to do something like this for example this is how I would get the `sourcePath` in my current SSIS package I am working with `string sourcePath = Dts.Variables["User::sourcePath"].Value.ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

Ben,

Any reason why you are using the wrapper assemblies? [IDTSPackage100](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.wrapper.idtspackage100.aspx) interface does not contain the Variables property. But the [Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.package.aspx) class found in the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime namespace contains the Variables property.

So use the Application and Package classes from the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime namespace (found in the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS assembly) instead of the wrapper namespace/assembly and you should be able to access the Variables property.

Update:
If you still want to use the wrapper namespace, you can cast the IDTSPackage100 object to the IDTSContainer100 object and then access the Variables from there.

```
IDTSContainer100 container = (IDTSContainer100)pkg;
container.Variables["User::mode"].Value = "test";
```

Update 2:
The call on [Execute method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522854.aspx) would then look like this:

```
pkg.Execute(null, container.Variables, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I need to use IDTS as the server i am installing on is quite old.

Comment: Didn't quite understand your comment. Are you saying that you cannot add references to the ManagedDTS assembly? Are you unable to find the location of the dll or is the dll not available at all?

Comment: Ben...updated my answer to continue using the wrapper assemblies. Having done that, I would recommend using the ManagedDTS assembly if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do i then pass the parameters when i execute the package? It wont let me pass container in:                 
`Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.DTSExecResult pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, container, null, null, null);`

Comment: Ben...the signature of the Execute method says it accepts a IDTSVariables object as the second input (and not a container)...so supply the IDTSVariables object. I am updating the answer to show the execution call.